# In England: ground or air based heat pump?

Tags: heating

Weather is not too extreme in southern England, will not need a/c. Want to install central heating for the first time in an old Victorian house. There are no radiators, no base board units, no under-floor heating, nothing. Well, a lot of chimneys and wood/coal stoves in fireplaces. Will be doing all the right things re. insulation and windows.  Want to be as green as possible, also independent of net if possible. Looking into geo-thermal but am not sure if govt. incentives make it worthwhile. Any advice welcome.

Comment: Such an open-ended question might better be addressed at a site like http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/qa

Comment: thanks for that tip but it is impossible to register with that site given their contradictory password directives.

Comment: I have an account... If I could do it, so can you!

Answer (score 1):

A ground-source heap pump is a custom-made-site-specific piece of equipment, and as such, will be more expensive and failure-prone. On the plus side, it will be more energy-efficient than the compressor of an air-source heat pump system. With today's super-efficient air-source heat pumps, you'd be looking at a coefficient of performance (COP) of ≤ 3 for air-source and ≤ 4 for ground-source. Both are very good. In general, I would favor an air-source heat pump due to lower upfront costs, higher reliability, and greater ease of maintenance and replacement.

But the real question for your situation will be distribution. You say you're installing central heat and are talking about heat pumps; I assume this means you'll be adding ducts. But even with ducts for distribution, a victorian house with a lot of small rooms and multiple stories will be much more comfortable to heat using modern equipment if you also super-insulate it. You should pay very close attention to your air-sealing and insulation details, and budget more than you think for this.  And buy better windows than you think you need. Definitely triple pane. Better to spend more on the building envelope and less on mechanical equipment than the reverse!

If you want to be "net zero" you need all your mechanicals to be electric (no gas or oil), and you'll want to keep your interior electric load as low as possible. LED lights, no huge plasma TVs, etc. And you'll need a lot of solar PV to generate the electricity required to run everything. In cloudy England, that will be quite a lot! To deal with this, you might want to look into solar-trackers, per-panel micro-inverters, and even residential wind turbines. You'll need to have a net metering arrangement with your municipal electric company/service as well.

Comment: No, don't want air ducts. So I guess the air-source heat pump would be wrong way to go.  Or, can an air-source heat pump also deliver heat to under-floor coils, which I might put in in the area of the house most used, the big kitchen. And, unfortunately, being the northern twin, there is not a lot of south-facing roof for pv. I am not aware that wind turbines are pemitted within residential neighborhoods in England. So, it looks like I may just have to give up and go with a gas-fired boiler and radiators. Pity.

Comment: If you don't want ducts, you have two options: 1. multiple point-source ductless mini-split heat pumps, or 2. a boiler or air-to-water heat pump to feed a hydronic heating system.

Comment: And there's no reason to avoid heat pumps just because offsetting their electricity consumption with PV would be difficult. Depending on your local gas and electricity rates, it may actually be cheaper to use electric heat pumps than gas. For example, a heat pump with a coefficient of performance of 3 will generate roughly 10,000 BTUs of heat per kWh. If one kWh costs you $0.10, and a therm of natural gas costs you $1.00, then the costs are roughly equal (assuming a 97% efficient boiler; with a worse boiler, the heat pump would be cheaper).

Comment: Any thoughts on multiple point-source ductless mini-split heat pumps (the first time I hear of something like that) to heat under-floor coils?

Comment: The multi-head ductless mini-split units are part of an air-to-air system; they blow air rather than heating water. However you would get air conditioning for free with ductless mini-split heat pumps. Heating water for radiators or radiant floor tubes would be accomplished with a single central unit (boiler or air-to-water heat pump) with zoned coils.

Comment: In the meantime have discovered that geology (thick clay deposits) makes an open-loop GSHP impossible. So, I'm still working on a vertical closed-loop option. Forced air systems architecturally impractical, and a/c un-called-for here. Feasibility probe for GSHP would cost about $600, but county facility might want to share expense. On the house, work begins Monday! Is it wise to install under-floor heating and radiators, with heat source -- whether GSHP or gas boiler -- to be worked out later?

Comment: No. Most people with under-floor radiant heat never use it because the floor isn't really the right place for it--especially with high mass floors of concrete. If you're sure you want radiant heat, stick to radiators or radiant hydronic panels on the walls. A GSHP hooked up to hydronic radiant heaters will be very nice, but of course, very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on both the outside and the inside layout of the house. 
I would approach it like this: I guess you have 4 main options, two for the source and two for delivering the heat.

Practicality may decide the source for you.

On delivery, to get hot water as well as space heating from a heat pump system, you must deliver the heat to water.

While the greenest most efficient option is your goal, when choosing, also keep in mind that electricity costs more than gas and the efficiency of the system depends on the difference between the source and delivery temperatures.

Perhaps consider a combination of systems, if there is not a single ideal fit for your house.

---

**Ground Source**

Pros:

Source temperature is higher than air source in the winter, making the system more efficient for heating in the winter and more suitable for producing hot water in the winter.

No outside noise.

Cons:

Requires sufficient garden area and digging up the garden to install/refurbish. Buried equipment cannot be inspected.

Alternatively requires borehole(s) if garden is relatively small. I don't know how hard it is to gain permission for those, even if the tube trains don't go under your house.

Source temperature is lower than air temperature part of the year, but heating load will be smaller at these times.

Requires floor space for hydronics unit.

Higher cost.

---

**Air source**

Pros:

Typically easier installation.

All equipment can be easily inspected/serviced.

Lower cost.

Cons:

Source temperature is low in the winter (less suitable for hot water); check that your model will at least give enough power for heating at -10C, where the effective COP including defrosting cycles may be around 2 (on par with a gas boiler in efficiency).

Noise. Modern units are very quiet, barely above suburban background noise.
No problem in the heating season with closed windows. However, noise may be an issue if used year round, early morning to produce hot water.

Noise levels must still fit within permitted development levels or planning permission will be required.

---

**Delivery to air**

Pros:

Takes no floor space.

Instant heating - full power within a couple of minutes.

Low delivery temperature - not much above 20C.

Lower cost.

Cons:

Very quiet, fan noise is not a problem on a decent unit, but of course noisier than a silent radiator.

Multiple units and/or thoughtful placement of them needed. For example, to cover several rooms in a storey, a unit might be placed in and heat a corridor more than you otherwise would. Or you may want two units in the main storey and just one in the corridor to give a bit of heat to bedrooms upstairs.

You cannot get subsidies for units that are able to cool also.

---

**Delivery to water**

Pros:

Can produce or help produce hot water although this requires high delivery temperature.

Low delivery temperature for underfloor coils.

Best possibility for integration with solar thermal (or combined thermal/photovoltaic panels).

Cons:

High delivery temperature required for radiators - reduces efficiency.

Works best with large radiators (with lots of ribs).

Requires space for hydronics unit/water tank.

Higher cost.

---

I like air-source as there are no ground loops to dig in/up and maintain.

I like the idea of delivery to water as you can use it for hot water too and potentially integrate with solar panels later, plus you can adjust heating room by room as normal with radiators, thus you can turn the heating down in rooms in your 3 storey mansion you don't use etc.

But I also like delivery to air as it is simpler/cheaper, comes on virtually instantly, ie. you can heat 100% on demand and it is very efficient (SCOP > 4) except for the worst part of winter. But even then a proper system is not less efficient than an A rated condensing boiler, although at the coldest times it may cost more to run.

If the house layout works for air to air, then it is perhaps also worth considering that in connection with a combi boiler for hot water, unless you want to avoid gas completely (obviously a yearly heat pump service and a yearly gas boiler service is approx. twice the cost of just one of the two).

That would be both a fairly simple and not too costly system - radiators plus hydronics will also cost, plus my feeling is you will be using a good deal of electricity to heat water from air source.
In theory you can recover that with solar panels, but they also cost to begin with.